# MS Access event-driven Data Macro to update table (example)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-data-macro

I have imported some data into Access from Excel. Now I want to write a code similar to trigger which will update another table whenever I get new data from Excel.

I know I cannot write a trigger in Access, so I am trying to use a Data Macro. Can anyone provide me help in how to do this using a data macro?

Comment: How is the excel data added?  Copy and paste or with macro or VBA?

Comment: import option from Access

Comment: the only thing I'm aware of is how to execute something on a form with `BeforeUpdate`...  I'm not sure how to do this with a macro, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say that you have a table named [Events] and you are importing data from Excel and appending it to the table

```
ID  EventName              EventType           EventDate 
--  ---------------------  ------------------  ----------
 1  New Staff Orientation  Training: in-house  2013-06-07
 2  TGIF barbecue lunch    Social              2013-06-14
```

Say that you also have a table named [EventTypes] to keep track of the categories that can be assigned to events. The [EventType] values coming in from the Excel data need to be approved to avoid unnecessary duplication, typos, etc.. Your [EventTypes] table looks like this

```
EventType           Added                Approved
------------------  -------------------  -------------------
Training: in-house  2013-06-01 09:15:33  2013-06-01 09:37:16
Social              2013-06-07 10:01:23  2013-06-07 10:22:00
```

You can create an "After Insert" data macro on the [Events] table to insert new [EventType] values into the [EventTypes] table like this:

**SetLocalVar**
            Name  NotFound
            Expression  = True

**Look Up A Record In  EventTypes**
            **Where Condition  =[EventTypes].[EventType]=[Events].[EventType]**

**SetLocalVar**
                Name  NotFound
                Expression  = False

**If**  [NotFound]  **Then**

**Create a Record In  EventTypes**

**SetField**
                    Name  EventTypes.EventType
                    Value  = [Events].[EventType]

**SetField**
                    Name  EventTypes.Added
                    Value  = Now()

**End If**

Now if you import an Event with a new EventType...

```
ID  EventName              EventType           EventDate 
--  ---------------------  ------------------  ----------
 1  New Staff Orientation  Training: in-house  2013-06-07
 2  TGIF barbecue lunch    Social              2013-06-14
 3  Bathtub races          Team Building       2013-06-15
```

...the data macro will automatically add it to the EventTypes table

```
EventType           Added                Approved
------------------  -------------------  -------------------
Training: in-house  2013-06-01 09:15:33  2013-06-01 09:37:16
Social              2013-06-07 10:01:23  2013-06-07 10:22:00
Team Building       2013-06-11 08:38:37
```